# Fischer Projection

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

[image]

i'm confused of how to get the Fischer projection of the molecule on the top. i can see that the hydrogen and OH group are sticking out. 
However i don't understand how the CH2OH group is pointing away. From my perspective the bond it is pointing straight down. i would appreciate some help.

Comment: Forget the table.

Comment: Stand up higher so that that bond is pointing more away from you.

Answer (score 0):

You drew it correctly. Fischer projections don't give you the option of drawing a bond in the plane of the paper. You have to choose (a) coming out of the page, or (b) going behind the page. In your example, the hydrogen and hydroxide are definitely coming out of the page. The other two bonds have to be represented as going back into the page.

It might make more sense if you imagine rotating the molecule a little so the CH2OH is actually pointing back a little. You would still have the hydrogen and hydroxide coming forward and the aldehyde going back.

Comment: Here is a 3D tutorial: http://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Fischer_projection